# Javascript function lost after an AJAX updated a data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a data table with a search function and a page function. These functions are added by jquery.dataTables.js and dataTables.bootstrap.min.js.

And I have an ajax to update the table when user select another date range.

```
<div id="data_table">
    <table......>
    ......                  
    ......                               
    </table>
</div>


<script>
    function update_table_data(){
        var startday = $("#start").val();
        var endday = $("#end").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "/test/test_update/",
            method : "POST",
            data : {
              'start': startday,
              'end': endday
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success:function(response) {
                console.log('response success');
                $("#data_table").html(response)
            },
            error:function(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

It updated the table correctly. However, all the page/search function are lost.

How can I do it without reload the page?

(I'm using django 2 with python 3.4)

Comment: You will have to re-initialize the data table.  You are completely replacing it.

Comment: My guess is that response doesn't contain the HTML code for the page/search functions, and you're updating #data_table with that response.

Comment: @trincot  did you mean `$("#data_table table")` ?  The data_table is the outer div of a table.

Comment: Indeed, @Taplar, so forget the shorter code ;-)

Comment: So, user3114168, try after `$("#data_table").html(response)` to apply again the plugin's method on the new table: $("#data_table table").DataTable()`.

Comment: @Trincot, just add "$("#data_table table").DataTable()" to the new line? 
It show an error "DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2"
Sorry, Since I'm new to ajax, I'm not sure what .DataTable() is doing.

Comment: Please post the exact `response` you get, or at least the first 50 characters of it.

Comment: Why not just use the DataTables methods for updating the data with ajax?

Comment: Indeed, muecas that is much better still.